Expo /react-native-firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call firebase.initializeApp()
I am using react native firebase npm module https://rnfirebase.io/auth/usage with expo so if followed docs and created firebasse android and ios apps and downloaded the google.services and GoogleInfo.plist files and configured with the project.
https://rnfirebase.io/auth/usage#listening-to-authentication-state
As mention in the docs i am adding listner that listines the auth state changes as provided in docs
My entrypoing file looks like below
  const [initializing, setInitializing] = useState(true);
  function onAuthStateChanged(user: any) {
    if (initializing) setInitializing(false);
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    const subscriber = auth().onAuthStateChanged(onAuthStateChanged);
    return subscriber; // unsubscribe on asunmount
  }, []);

  if (initializing) return null;
 

I am getting error  Error: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call firebase.initializeApp() from auth().onAuthStateChanged(onAuthStateChanged) auth() method.
if i remove this subscription works runs just fine with expo development app.
As mentino in docs with expo we dont need to call initiliseApp of firebase
Whats wrong here?
I want to subscribe a listner that listnes the auth state change
 plugins: [
      '@react-native-firebase/app',
      '@react-native-firebase/auth',
      '@react-native-firebase/firestore',
      '@react-native-google-signin/google-signin',
      [
        'expo-build-properties',
        {
          ios: {
            useFrameworks: 'static',
          },
        },
      ],
      [
        'expo-document-picker',
        {
          iCloudContainerEnvironment: 'Production',
        },
      ],
    ],
    ios: {
      googleServicesFile: './GoogleService-Info.plist',
      supportsTablet: true,
      bundleIdentifier: '........',
    },
    android: {
      googleServicesFile: './google-services.json',
      adaptiveIcon: {
        foregroundImage: './assets/adaptive-icon.png',
        backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
      },
      package: '........',
    },






 "@react-native-firebase/app": "20.5.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "20.5.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/firestore": "20.5.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/functions": "20.5.0",
    "@react-native-google-signin/google-signin": "^12.1.0",


Please update your post to show the configuration of RN-Firebase in your app.json or app.config.js.  It is that configuration which is used by the call to initializeApp() in the native layer by the RNF library.

android: {
googleServicesFile: './google-services.json',
adaptiveIcon: {
foregroundImage: './assets/adaptive-icon.png',
backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
},
package: 'com.josh.training_and_fitness',
},

plugins: [
'@react-native-firebase/app',
'@react-native-firebase/auth',
'@react-native-firebase/firestore',
'@react-native-google-signin/google-signin',

Today again i got this issue once i installed 'expo-document-picker'

Error: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call firebase.initializeApp(), js engine: hermes
ERROR  Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:

Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the curr


Invariant Violation: TurboModuleRegistry.getEnforcing(...): 'RNGoogleSignin' could not be found. Verify that a module by this name is registered in the native binary.Bridgeless mode: false.
