Expo project is not loading No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call firebase.initializeApp(), js engine: hermes
I was working on expo app it was working fine until I installed
"expo-document-picker": "~12.0.2",
and rebuilded the project I got error:
No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call firebase.initializeApp(), js engine: hermes

ios: {
      googleServicesFile: './GoogleService-Info.plist',
      supportsTablet: true,
      bundleIdentifier: 'com.josh.training-and-fitnesse',
    },
    android: {
      googleServicesFile: './google-services.json',
      adaptiveIcon: {
        foregroundImage: './assets/adaptive-icon.png',
        backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
      },
      package: 'com.josh.training_and_fitness',
    }

Above is the app.config.json file.
One more thing I am not using:
if (!firebase.apps.length) {
  firebase.initializeApp({
    // Your Firebase configuration here
  });
}

Since, I include service.json and plist files.
My package JSON looks like:
"dependencies": {
    "@dev-plugins/react-query": "^0.0.7",
    "@expo/config": "^8.1.1",
    "@expo/metro-config": "^0.10.0",
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^14.0.0",
    "@react-native-community/blur": "^4.4.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "20.5.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "20.5.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/firestore": "20.5.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/functions": "20.5.0",
    "@react-native-google-signin/google-signin": "^12.1.0",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.20",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.2",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.26",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.29",
    "@shopify/flash-list": "1.6.4",
    "@shopify/react-native-skia": "1.2.3",
    "@tanstack/react-query": "^5.40.0",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.73.0",
    "d3": "^7.9.0",
    "expo": "51.0.8",
    "expo-application": "~5.9.1",
    "expo-build-properties": "~0.12.1",
    "expo-constants": "~16.0.1",
    "expo-dev-client": "4.0.14",
    "expo-document-picker": "~12.0.2",
    "expo-font": "~12.0.5",
    "expo-keep-awake": "~13.0.2",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~13.0.2",
    "expo-linking": "~6.3.1",
    "expo-router": "~3.5.14",
    "expo-secure-store": "~13.0.1",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.27.4",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.12.1",
    "expo-system-ui": "~3.0.4",
    "expo-web-browser": "~13.0.3",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "lottie-react-native": "6.7.0",
    "nativewind": "^2.0.11",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.74.1",
    "react-native-chart-kit": "^6.12.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.16.1",
    "react-native-modal": "^13.0.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.10.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.10.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-view": "^1.1.1",
    "react-native-screens": "3.31.1",
    "react-native-simple-line-chart": "^0.34.4",
    "react-native-svg": "15.2.0",
    "react-native-ui-datepicker": "^2.0.2",
    "react-native-uuid": "^2.0.2",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@tsconfig/react-native": "^3.0.5",
    "@types/d3": "^7.4.3",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.12",
    "@types/react": "~18.2.45",
    "@types/react-navigation": "^3.4.0",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.7",
    "jest": "^29.2.1",
    "jest-expo": "~51.0.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "tailwindcss": "3.3.2",
    "typescript": "~5.3.3"
  }

Whenever I do npx expo start Iget above error earlier, it was working fine.
Cleaned the cache and rebuilt the project by using expo sdk 51,  but still making errors.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78533943/expo-react-native-firebase-no-firebase-app-default-has-been-created-call?noredirect=1#comment138452129_78533943
